# git pull then git push shows too many files changed on merge

Tags: git

I am working on a project with one other developer. He pushes a bunch of a code. Then I "git pull". There is a merge conflict in one single file. I fix that merge conflict then commit and push the code. Why does github show that in my commit, I changed ALL the files that the other developer touched? Why doesn't it simply show changes to the one merged file, since that's the only file I touched!

This make tracking changes very difficult. If one were to look at the commit, it looks like I changed 100 files, when in fact I changed one line in one file. How do I change my workflow to stop this?

Comment: Is it a public repository? (It would be much easier if we could have a look at it.)

Comment: Is anyone of you using windows? (there might be some nasty newline issue involved.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you merge, you are bringing all the changes from the merged branch, and your commit reflects that. Note that when viewing the history of a particular file, or doing a `git blame`, etc., these merge commits are normally not included, so it shouldn't throw off your tracking of who changed what.

Comment: Okay, this makes sense. My commit shows so many files changed today, but clicking on the individual files shows that they changed "2 days ago". If these files changed two days ago, then why doesn't clicking on my commit simply show the files that had  actually changed, in other words why doesn't it just show the single file that actually had a conflict not the 100 other files that other developer worked on?

Comment: Because they did change, relative to one of the parents of the merge (i.e. the primary parent).

Comment: To view the commit where just the single file changed, look at the primary parent of the merge commit.